# Каким выражением описать все файлы и папки, включая скрытые

Tags: linux, shell

Есть папка, в ней другие файлы и папки (в том числе скрытые), которые принадлежат разным пользователям. Хочу все присвоить текущему пользователю:

```
sudo chown user:group *
```

Однако эта команда работает только для не-скрытых файлов и папок. Догадался, что для скрытых нужно так (правда, это ещё и `.` затрагивает):

```
sudo chown user:group .*
```

А что указать вместо *, чтобы были сразу обе категории?  Нужно решение, не привязанное к chown, то есть чтобы работало с любой другой командой. Подозреваю, что есть какое-нибудь простое решение с wildcard'ами, но я его не знаю.

Есть ещё find, но он рекурсивный и гораздо более громоздкий. Не годится.

```
find . -exec chown user:group {} \+
```

Comment: ls -a1 | xargs -n1 'file'  например

Comment: @DmitryV.: это почти как с find, тоже поезд. Но уже лучше.  Подозреваю, что должно быть какое-то выражение, буквально в пару символов.

Comment: Не уверен..  У вас достаточно специфичные требования - чтоб работало для всех и не было рекурсивным.

Этот "поезд" можно назвать скриптом с имененм в две буквы и положить в ~/bin  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нет экзотических имен вроде `..x`, то совсем просто: `command .[^.]* *`

Первое выражение -- все имена из двух и более символов, начинающиеся с `.`, кроме `..`, а второе все знают.

Comment: И это как раз решает проблему с «рекурсивным подъемом» до `/`, верно?

Comment: Да, решает. Кстати, "экзотику" очевидно можно добавить так -- `..?*`

Comment: а `../*` не попадёт в фильтр `..?*`?

Comment: Нет. Таких имен (`./tram-pam-pam` или `../`) вообще нет. Это пути, которые интерпретируются программой bash (как это происходит см., например, [man 3 glob](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob)), а среди имен  текущего оглавления их нет.

Comment: спасибо, изучу.

Answer (score 2):

Селектор `*` определяет доступ ко всем **не** скрытым файлам и директориям. Вместо него используйте ссылку на текущую директорию - `.` (точка). Т.о. команда должна выглядеть так:

```
sudo chown user:group . -R
```

Ключ `-R` добавляет рекурсивность.

Comment: `sudo chown user:group . -R` меняет принадлежность файлов в директории и самой директории. И ключ -R есть не в каждой утилите.

Comment: То есть если я хочу, например, положить каждый файл в отдельный архив, то такой синтаксис не подойдет.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo chown user:group $(ls -A)
any-command $(ls -A)
```

С параметром `-A` команда `ls` возвращает все файлы и папки, включая скрытые, но не включая `.` и `..`

---

[Дополнение от andy.47](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/466990/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5/467000?noredirect=1#comment517131_467000):

Не используйте `.*`, особенно с `rm`, так как `sudo rm .*` эквивалентно `sudo rm -rf /`.

Comment: Мне как раз в голову это пришло, только имей ввиду, под .* к сожалению попадают еще `.` и `..` в чем легко убедится дав `echo .*` иногда это мешает, например команде `ls` которая умудрится залезть на уровень выше.

Comment: Боюсь это не лечится. ну можно конечно попробовать развернуть повилдакрду, отфильтровать седом и как то вернуть в командную строку, но боюсь после этого find вам покажется самым элементарным решением :)

Comment: Я поставил '-', т.к. команда `sudo rm * .*` эквивалентна команде `sudo rm -rf /`. Не вздумайте. Либо как советует @NickVolynkin, либо @DmitryV

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ок) Просто лично через это проходил. Свежий бэкап был, к счастью)

Comment: @andy.37: а почему `* .*` эквивалентно `-rf /`? Что-то не пойму, как тут должна сработать рекурсия.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, все просто: `..\..` удовлетворяет шаблону `.*`. И `..\..\..`. И т.д. В итоге решил (в свое время) через `ls -A`. Уже не помню, с `xargs` или нет, но в эту сторону копал. Вообще любопытно, что в линухе нет тривиального способа сделать что-то со ВСЕМИ файлами в папке, не трогая саму папку.

Comment: @andy.37: обнаружил, что `$(ls -A)` ломается, если есть файлы или папки с пробелом в имени. Есть идеи, как это обойти?

Comment: @NickVolynkin с пробелами поможет `ls -A | xargs -d'\n' any-command`

Answer (score 2):

Для **bash** есть режим устанавливаемый встроенной командой

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

После чего `*` не будет игнорировать имена начинающиеся с точки кроме `.` и `..` . Похожий эффект достижим установкой переменной `GLOBIGNORE`

```
GLOBIGNORE='.'
```

В кавычки можно поставить игнорируемые имена через двоеточие, `.` и `..` будут игнорироваться в любом случае, просто что-то должно быть, чтобы переменная начала действовать.

В некоторых дистрибутивах sh ссылается на dash или что-то другое, в скрипте важно явно указать, чтобы запускался **bash**.

Для возврата в стандартный режим выполните:

```
shshopt -u dotglob
unset GLOBIGNORE
```

Comment: Есть проблема: работаю на десятке удаленных машин, там проблематично менять настройки bash – могут сломаться какие-нибудь скрипты. Но на своей действительно можно так сделать, спасибо.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Не нужно менять глобальные настройки. Выполните одну из команд внутри вашего скрипта, режим не затронет другие скрипты, если они выполняются не через команду `.` или `source`.